# Python: How to create a simple frame in Kivy?

Tags: python, mobile, kivy

How can I create a simple frame in Kivy (Python for mobile), which will include a simple TextBox ?

Thanks guys

Comment: You are aware of the fact that Kivy is thoroughly documented here: http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/intro.html , right? There are usage examples too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest name I know of that uses (or used) wxPython is probably Dropbox:

- [How does Dropbox use Python on Windows and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678180/how-does-dropbox-use-python-on-windows-and-os-x)

This web page implies that NASA also uses wxPython:

- https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/docs/DOC-2424/diff?secondVersionNumber=4

Google uses Python itself for all kinds of things and has been a big supporter of Python. They provide Python bindings to many of their product's APIs for example.

You might also check out the following for less well-known projects:

- http://freecode.com/tags/wxpython

[Whyteboard](https://code.google.com/p/whyteboard/) was getting popular for a while too.

There is significant movement away from desktop development to web and mobile development. For mobile, one of the best Python projects out there is [Kivy](http://kivy.org/). For the web, you have a lot of choices:

- django
- flask
- pyramid
- Plone / Zope
- web2py

I have seen some pretty impressive desktop GUIs created using PyQt and IronPython, so I can't say that desktop GUI development is totally dead.